# php hive thrift client multiple statements

Tags: php, hadoop, hive

I am new to hadoop/hive. I am trying to run multiple hive statements at a time which works on terminal but not when using thrift client.

I have followed this 
http://nousefor.net/55/2011/12/php/hbase-and-hive-thrift-php-client/
to connect to hive thrift server. it works for single statement like "`select * from sdf`" but not for "`use default; select * from sdf`;"

It gives following error:

> "Error: Query returned non-zero code: 11, cause: FAILED: Parse Error:
>   line 1:11 mismatched input ';' expecting EOF near 'default'"

please help on how to run multiple statements